# What is the best-practice for circular lego staircase construction?

Tags: building, piece-usage

Aside from using the grey key-hole shapes, I'm looking for a Lego-standard or best-practice method for building a circular Lego staircase?

Requirements:

- 6-8 studs "wide" (from the center to outer edge)

  Sturdy, play-able construction

  Connects at either 90 or 180 degrees to a floor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a brick-built spiral staircase in the Pet Shop:

[image]

That's definitely the most common way to do it. You just build up around a central point. This can be expanded to use longer or wider steps:

[image: Staircase from LEGO.com LDD gallery]

[image]
http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/267772

You can also use 2x2 turntables if you need more strength and/or larger stairs:

[image]
http://www.popscreen.com/v/6UIWz/Tutorial-Lego-Spiral-Staircase

Comment: In the last case, since the rotation point is centered on the plate, it means you can attach steps one to another easily, either at the end (replace the 1x2 tile by a 1x1 tile and a 1x1 plate on which the next step is attached) or closer to the center if you prefer. Note however that this fixes the angles and that it probably won't be exact at the end of the stairs.