# What is the best way to make a staircase?

Tags: building

I have built a Bat Cave from some bookcases and lego base plates. ( http://alice-yarns.co.uk/blog/2013/11/17/the-batcave-part-i/ ) I want to add staircases for the characters to move between each of the three shelves. But what is the best way of doing this?

I wondered about making it purely from lego bricks but I can't see how this could be stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the size of your project you'd certainly need lots of bricks if you wanted it to be built entirely out of LEGO.

Check out the 3rd and 4th models in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRP8HcEaRpQ

Or if you'd prefer to have spiral staircases and have lots of turnplates you could try building one according to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4sA9abH8so or this answer: [What is the best-practice for circular lego staircase construction?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/what-is-the-best-practice-for-circular-lego-staircase-construction)

But I think Batman would rather have a lift than a staircase :)

Comment: Fab! I love the spiral staircase. I hadn't thought of making a lift. And I think that would be perfect. :-) thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Building a staircase out of bricks is easy enough, but uses a lot of brick pieces, as zovits already answered. If you want to achieve something faster, with fewer pieces, you could look into the [spiral-staircase-piece](http://rebrickable.com/parts/40243)

[image]

or the [regular staircase piece](http://rebrickable.com/parts/30134).

[image]

The spiral staircase piece combines with some plate+pin pieces ([bottom](http://rebrickable.com/parts/2460), [top](http://rebrickable.com/parts/2476a)) and some [posts](http://rebrickable.com/parts/40244). You can connect as many posts together as you want using a [pin](http://rebrickable.com/parts/2780).

The advantage of using the spiral staircase is mainly the simplicity of it; it's not that versatile a piece, but it works for its purpose and does have a nice round edge. Plus the stairs can be rotated, which allows for a "hidden staircase" feature.

The advantage of using the regular staircase piece is that it is very sturdy and it takes up very little space. You can build a similar staircase using the [inverted slope](http://rebrickable.com/parts/3660) and some 1x4 plates but it isn't as strong (and it's slightly taller).

[image]