# How can I make a spiral staircase with basic blocks at right angles?

Tags: building

Quite simply, how do I make a spiral like a staircase, but with only these blocks?

[image]

There is also a 8x2 block, but my brother has it. Because it is quite an old set, I need a spiral staircase without 45 degree angles. The best I have made is this...

[image]

....made with these components: [image]

What is a better alternative?

For Ambo100, it is not needed to support any weight, I  merely make these things for pleasure. Additionally, I require it to continue for infinite iterations of layers. And obviously, it need to be vertical. Finally, I would like it to be solid when "running" along it, just to be annoying. =)

Important: I forgot to note this, but my set is based around the 2 x 4 blocks.

Comment: How many bricks high do you need to go? Does it need to support any weight? [I managed to build a helix limited to six blocks high](http://imgur.com/a/ACE5Z),
 but it uses 45 degree angles.

Comment: Related, but not a dupe due to your part limitations: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/what-is-the-best-practice-for-circular-lego-staircase-construction/1903

Comment: @jncraton , that is the post I referred to for this idea in the first place.

Comment: I updated my answer to only cover the bricks I think you're using - is that better?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid, yeah. (Neither did I say it was bad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the limited brick options, and the "it needs to be solid" constraint, I present my "Minecraft Spiral Stair" in LEGO form, and to provide "inifite height", I've gone for a "hung" support option:

1. Start with two 2x2, a 2x4 and a 2x6 in this configuration:
   [image: Repeating step]
2. Add more steps as you need rotating around the lower 2x2 brick:
   [image: Infinite height stair]

(Key: Yellow: 2x2, Blue: 2x4, White: 2x6)

Comment: Sorry, Only the pieces above

Answer (score 3):

Depending upon the structural integrity required, you can connect the 4x2 bricks by one corner peg consistently (upper left most corner when viewed horizontally) stacked on top of each other, yet rotated such that the side of the brick is against the lower level peg (in upper one from the left on the lower brick). This will make a weak spiral yet with adjustable and relatively tight angles with one step per brick layer.

Comment: There are many things wrong with the answer,.but the main problems are that you have not provided images for clarity, neither have you answered my question. Not at all. _, it is not needed to support any weight, I merely make these things for pleasure. Additionally, I require it to continue for infinite iterations of layers. And obviously, it need to be vertical. Finally, I would like it to be solid when "running" along it, just to be annoying._ None of the criteria met.

Comment: @simplest_mathematics I agree that this answer could be improved with an image, but I think your comment is a little harsh. This answer sounds a lot like what Ambo proposed, and that seems reasonable to me. It's true that it doesn't use only 90 degree angles, but it does provide another option using only basic bricks. Honestly, I think this answer is pretty good, especially for a first post.

Comment: Fair enough, you should look at my first bad answers lol!  But I'm not saying that it is bad, I am saying a little more consideration of the specifications should be implemented in the answer @jncraton